# AzureDevops process custom rules can't change Team project

Tags: azure-devops

I have problem with configuration of AzureDevOps process.

My goal is simply automate work items - when work item changes state to done or is in state done on certain board I want to transfer it on other board.

I tried to achieve this by applying custom rules in my organization. Example:
I navigate to Organization Settings, select Process then I select process from list (is inherited from Scrum parent). Then I select bug (for example) and go to rules tab.

[Here is screen of my configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvtN1.png)

Both `Board no.1` and `Board no.2` exist as Team Projects. I've added clearing `assign to` field and this one works properly.

I wondering if there is much easier way to automate moving work items through boards or team projects on status change.

Answer (score 0):

> I wondering if there is much easier way to automate moving work items
> through boards or team projects on status change.

For this issue, I am afraid there is no easier way to achieve this requirement. Azure Devops has provided a built-in custom rule function to achieve this. This is already a very easy way.

In addition, we can also achieve this through the azure logic app, but this needs to be set in the azure portal. I don’t think it will be more convenient than custom rules.

[image]

To move work items to another project, you must be a member of the Project Administrators group or be [granted explicit permissions to move work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#move-delete-permissions).

Comment: Can you have idea why custom rules not working in my case?

Comment: To move work items to another project, you must be a member of the Project Administrators group or be [granted explicit permissions to move work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#move-delete-permissions). Please check this.